# Google C2D_MESSAGE Application does not define permission?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i have problem in my code, I've just followed the google guide for GCM push messaging and am getting this error:

```
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droidersuin.project/com.droidersuin.pushnotifications.PushMainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.droidersuin.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1959)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.droidersuin.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
06-07 10:51:04.371: E/AndroidRuntime(29686):
```

and this my manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.droidersuin.pushnotifications.RegisterPushActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity
       android:name="com.droidersuin.pushnotifications.PushMainActivity"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.droidersuin.pushnotifications" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.droidersuin.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService" />


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />  
<permission 
    android:name="com.droidersuin.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.droidersuin.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

this my package :

[image: my package]

any body help me.. ? I hope someone can help with this, always frustrating when you are following a tutorial.

Comment: did you resolved this issue? If so then can you share the solution please?

Answer (score 10):

After adding the permission, it should be look like this

```
<permission android:name="your package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="your package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting the `com.droidersuin.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE` permission, but you defined the `com.droidersuin.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE` permission.

What's the `pakcage` specified in your manifest? Do didn't include that part. The C2D_MESSAGE permission should match that package.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the checkManifet function on a different class which is on another package ?

You should put the GCMIntentService on the same package (where it is supposed you will manage the regId). Take a look at the checkManifest function from the [GCM source code](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java?r=8094cc6410b7dc2db452eb19cc9274fda1b2d6a2)

```
 public static void checkManifest(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    String permissionName = packageName + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE";
    // check permission
    try {
        packageManager.getPermissionInfo(permissionName,
                PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Application does not define permission " + permissionName);
    }
 //....
 }
```

Put it on the same package and rename the manifest permisions.

Answer (score 0):

Move the definition to before the Application not after.